# Are accounts on Ganache Blockchain considered Nodes?

Tags: web3js, truffle, private-blockchain, ganache

I wanted to ask a question: the accounts on Ganache are nodes, for example
I mean, if I am in the project, I let the account send the transaction to another account
This process considers that you are node talking node????

Comment: Accounts and nodes are two completely unrelated concepts, can you try and clarify your question?

Comment: okay I had thought accounts are equal to nodes and Ganache is actually like a real blockchain
then I knowen Ganache is actually a one node

Comment: also, I want to make  a network of blockchains from Ganache